# How to increase the accuracy of a plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, recursion, precision-and-accuracy

I have the following code below:

```
num = 25;
U[x_] := 50*(Sech[1.5*(x - 5.8)])^4 - 0.14*(Sech[0.5*(x - 6.5)])^2
V[x_] := U[x] - U[3.8]
Plot[V[x], {x, 0, 4.75}, PlotRange -> All];
A := 1.05459^2*0.01/2/1.6726/1.60219
{vals, funs} =
NDEigensystem[-(A/x)*D[x*D[\[Psi][x], {x}], {x}] +
V[x]*\[Psi][x], \[Psi][x], {x, 0, 5}, num];
```

And I get the following graphic:

[image]

Here, as I expect there should not be such a sharp peak at the beginning of the plot. So I tried to increase a number of points for the plot:

```
Plot[Evaluate[funs[[25]]/
Sqrt[NIntegrate[x*(funs[[25]])^2, {x, 0, 5},
AccuracyGoal -> 10]]], {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> vals[[25]],
PlotRange -> All]
```

And get the following:

[image]

It's the same graph, but in different ranges. How can I do the same, but in range from 0 to 5?

Comment: I think PlotPoints is the option you need

Comment: This is not an issue of `Plot`. The interpolating function that you are using (`funs[[25]]`) already has this shape.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem does not seem to be in `Plot` but in `NDEigensystem`. Apparently, the default method used for your function is not ideal. If you provide a method explicitly it seems to work better.

```
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[
    -(A/x)*D[x*D[ψ[x], {x}], {x}] + V[x]*ψ[x], 
    ψ[x], 
    {x, 0, 5}, 
    num, 
    Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> 
                  {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}}];

Multicolumn[Plot[#, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All] & /@ funs]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]